# Shounen AI where a boy’s eyes tear up whenever he’s near a ghost

Tags: story-identification, ghost

It is about a boy who lives next to a temple’s cemetery and is sensitive to ghosts. His eyes always start tearing up when one is close to him. His neighbor and childhood friend lives at the temple and always saves him but doesn't want to become a monk himself.

Comment: What is an "AI" in this case? Is this a manga? An OVA? Full-length anime film? A series?

Comment: Ah, "Shounen Ai" is a term for "boy love" stories.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

[*Take Me to Heaven*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5071307-take-me-to-heaven) by Nase Yamato looks to be a good match.

[image: Front cover of Take Me to Heaven]

> He sees ghosts... and one sexy guy!
>
> High school student Fumiya possesses the ability to see things normal people can't: ghosts and spirits. Every time Fumiya sees one, he turns to the tall, handsome and popular Shogo, the son of a temple priest, for help. After being rescued time after time by Shogo, Fumiya can't resist developing certain feelings towards his savior. Watch as ghosts and spirits work to drive these two together!

And yes, his eyes water in the presence of ghosts.

[image: Panel with Fumiya's eyes watter as ghosts arrive]

Found with a search for `"shounen ai" temple graveyard ghosts`